# Pandas Indexing - Strange Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a strange indexing problem.

I have a dataframe "Full_Names_Copy" with a column that has string values with a letter B or M on the end that denotes 'billions' or 'millions'.

I'm iterating through the column to 1) check for the existence of the letter and 2) if the letter exists, remove the letter, convert to a float (and in the case of billions, multiply by 1000 to get all my values in 'millions')

My dataframe has a column 'Symbol' that is fully populated and I use that to set the range for iteration.

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(0,len(Full_Names_Copy['Symbol'])):
    letter = Full_Names_Copy.iloc[i,4][-1]
    if letter == 'B':
        test_int = float(Full_Names_Copy.iloc[i,4][0:len(Full_Names_Copy.iloc[i,4])-1])*1000 
    elif letter == 'M':
        test_int = float(Full_Names_Copy.iloc[i,4[0:len(Full_Names_Copy.iloc[i,4])-1])
    else:
        ### do some other stuff ###
```

so:

```
len(Full_Names_Copy['Symbol'])
```

returns a value.

```
letter = Full_Names_Copy.iloc[**row number entered here**,4][-1]
```

returns a 'B' or 'M' for selected row number

Yet when I run the full code above I get:

```
> TypeError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-a45d46e088cb> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(0,len(Full_Names_Copy['Symbol'])):
----> 2     letter = Full_Names_Copy.iloc[i,4][-1]
      3     if letter == 'B':
      4         test_int = float(Full_Names_Copy.iloc[i,4][0:len(Full_Names_Copy.iloc[i,4])-1])*1000
      5     elif letter == 'M':

TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this strange error.

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there are no `None` values in the `Symbol` column?

Another way of doing this is to put your conversion logic in a function, and to apply this function over the column.

```
def convert(amt):
    if not amt:
        return 0.0 # Handle None and empty strings
    num, sym = float(amt[:-1]), amt[-1]
    if sym == 'M':
        return num * 1e6
    if sym == 'B':
        return num * 1e9
    raise ValueError('Invalid suffix')
```

Then,

```
Full_Names_Copy.Symbol.map(convert, na_action='ignore')
```

This calls the `convert` function on each value in the `Symbol`, and returns a list containing the values returned. Of course, you can assign this back to the `Symbol` column.

```
Full_Names_Copy['Symbol'] = Full_Names_Copy.Symbol.map(convert, na_action='ignore')
```

Comment: There are no None values in Symbol.  Thanks for your suggestion!  I have to study it a bit to make sure I understand it.  Still would like to figure out why my way isn't working.

Comment: I made a minor edit to explain what this does. Also, if you want to dig into what happened in your code, you can do this `try: <problematic code> except: import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` -- This will give you a shell at the point where the exception happened and you can see for yourself what went wrong by inspecting the variables by simply printing them.

Comment: Thank you!  Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  There were null values in the column I was working on and Python seems not to like that I was trying to run operations on a null value.